# Cannot create hdf5 file with h5py.file()

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to write my results in two separate hdf5 files. My code works for one of them but produces an error for the other one, even though the code for both is identical. Here is my code:

```
def test(model, outfile_f3,outfile_f5):

    dtype = torch.FloatTensor

    path = args.imagefolder

    filenames = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.png')))
    N = len(filenames)


    f3_activations = []
    f5_activations = []
    for i in range(N):
        fname = filenames[i]
        print(fname)

        v = Image.open(fname)
        image = load_image(v, image_sizes['eig'])
        image = torch.from_numpy(image).type(dtype).cuda()
        image = image.unsqueeze(0)

        att, f3, f5, latent = model(image, segment=args.segment, add_offset=args.addoffset and args.segment, test=True)

        #latents.append(latent.detach()[0].cpu().numpy().flatten())
        #attended.append(att.detach()[0].cpu().numpy().flatten())
        f3_activations.append(f3.detach()[0].cpu().numpy().flatten())
        f5_activations.append(f5.detach()[0].cpu().numpy().flatten())

    file_f3 = h5py.File(outfile_f3, 'w')
    file_f3.create_dataset('f3_activations', data=np.array(f3_activations))
    file_f3.close()

    file_f5 = h5py.File(outfile_f5, 'w')
    file_f5.create_dataset('f5_activations', data=np.array(f5_activations))
    file_f5.close()

    #asciiList = [n.split('/')[-1][:-4].encode("ascii", "ignore") for n in filenames]
    #f.create_dataset('filenames', (len(asciiList), 1), 'S10', data=asciiList)
```

outfile_f3 and outfile_f5 have previously been defined as:

```
outfile_f3 = os.path.join('./output', 'f3_activations.hdf5')
outfile_f5 = os.path.join('.output','f5_activations.hdf5')
```

When I try to run the script that uses test function I get the following error:
File "record_f3_and_f5_actvations.py", line 109, in test
    file_f5 = h5py.File(outfile_f5, 'w')

File "/gpfs/milgram/project/yildirim/ms3542/conda_envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 408, in **init**
    swmr=swmr)

File "/gpfs/milgram/project/yildirim/ms3542/conda_envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 179, in make_fid

fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 108, in h5py.h5f.create

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '.output/f5_activations.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)

It has no problem with creating, opening and writing in the file f3_activations.hdf5, but for some reason, it can't do the same with f5_activations.hdf5

Comment: Dumb question: Why are you using `'./output'`, for `outfile_f3` and `'.output'`, for `outfile_f5`?

Comment: It's a typo. That's the reason it was giving me the error. Thank you!